# How to add description to appSetting?

Tags: .net, app-config

I want to develop config editor for app.config files. That i swhy I need to have description
field in every   record. 
Is it possible to add additional field to configuration section appSettings?
For example:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Provider" description ="Data Provider Name" value="SqlServer"/>
...
```

When I do this then app catch exception here

```
System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader configurationAppSettings = new System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader();
```

Comment: Well, I think it's clearer to use comments if it isn't a part of data you use in your app. If you need to read descripition value you should add custom section to your web.config

Comment: Not to be rude, but if you really want to develo an app.config editor, you should start to study what is an appSettings section

Comment: Thatnk you Steve, I know what is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at ConfigurationSection? you may want to check this article in msdn. Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3(v=vs.100).aspx